# How to unlock the USAS-12?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'd like to unlock the USAS-12. (I'm rank 32 right now)

Is it part of Back to Karkand expansion?

Comment: To check all other unlocks sign in at http://battlelog.battlefield.com and check your profile :)

Comment: If you're wanting it because everyone seems to be killing you with it, note that they will be nerfing it in an update shortly.

Comment: @SSumner: wow, really? At the moment when I find myself under its fire it's like if I'm trying to withstand alone a BPM attack, just a little bit lighter. No escape. Anyways thanks, good to know.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty bad. Here's a list of the upcoming updates:
http://gamerant.com/battlefield-3-tweaks-fixes-updates-patches-list-robk-135174/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is unlocked by reaching Rank 43

[image]

All unlocks can be seen in battlelog -> player stats -> weapons